# Unable to obtain correct parameter for React JSX action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, action

I have created a table in reactjs and would like to remove input a button that will remove the particular row when clicked. However, currently, the button will only remove the last row when clicked. As i debug, I found out that the parameters that I passed is not correct. May I know how to pass the row number to the removeRow correctly? Thank you.

```
createTable = () => {
    
    let rows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.tableSize; i++) {
      let cell = [];
      for (var idx = 0; idx < 8; idx++) {
        cell.push(
          <td
            contenteditable='true'
            onChange={(e) => {
              this.handleChangeTable(e, i, idx);
            }} //to incorporate event with other params
            key={`${i}-${idx}`}
            id={idx} //cell no
          ></td>
        );
      }
      rows.push(
        <tr key={i} id={i}>
          <img
            id={i}
            onClick={() => {
              this.removeRow(i);
            }}
            src={Image}
          />
          {cell}
        </tr>
      );
    }

    return rows;
  };
```

Here is the function for the removeRow:

```
removeRow = (row) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      let tableData = [...prevState.tableData];
      tableData.splice(row, 1);
      return { tableData };
    });
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      let tableSize = prevState.tableSize;
      tableSize--;
      return { tableSize };
    });
    console.log(`removed ${row}`);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you are subtracting **1** to **tableSize** every time you trigger ***removeRow***. Since you are using a for loop that is dependent on **tableSize**, it renders again with one less item *every time*.

You should loop through the **tableData** instead. Like this:

```
createTable = () => {
    const rows = [];
    const { tableData } = this.state;

    tableData.forEach((row, i) => {
        const cell = [];

        for (let idx = 0; idx < 8; idx++) {
            cell.push(
                <td
                    contenteditable='true'
                    onChange={e => this.handleChangeTable(e, i, idx)} //to incorporate event with other params
                    key={`${i}-${idx}`}
                    id={idx} //cell no
                ></td>
            );
        }

        rows.push(
            <tr key={i} id={i}>
                <img
                    id={i}
                    onClick={() => this.removeRow(i)}
                    src={Image}
                    alt={cell}
                />
                {cell}
            </tr>
        );
    });

    return rows;
};
```

I also changed your ***removeRow*** function into this:

```
removeRow = (rowIndex) => {
    const{ tableData } = this.state;

    tableData.splice(rowIndex, 1);

    this.setState({ tableData });
    console.log(`removed ${rowIndex}`);
};
```